# Custom Google Maps to open Marker Links

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a project where Google Maps markers open a link when clicked. The problem is that on the last entry in the array opens and not the preceding ones. I just can't see the problem. It populates on a template page in Wordpress, and I have used the wp_enqueue_script in the functions.php file. The header.php file contains the Google Maps API key. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: 32.5851061, lng: -89.8772196},
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
    setMarkers(map, communities);
  }
  var communities = [
  ['Oxford', 34.360004, -89.5233875, 'http://oxfordcycling.org'],
  ['Starkville', 33.4562909, -88.8322225, 'http://starkvillecyclingclub.org'],
  ['Natchez', 31.544537, -91.3862539,     'http://crookedlettercycling.com/communities/natchez'],
  ['Ridgeland', 32.42941, -90.1454013, 'http://ridgelandms.com']
  ];
  function setMarkers(map, locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var community = locations[i];
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(community[1], community[2]);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: community[0],
        url: community[3],
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: At least part of your problem may be that `...addListener(marker, ...)` is *outside* the `for` loop -- so only the last `marker` gets that treatment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event listener should be inside your for loop, otherwise only the last marker will receive click events.

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var community = locations[i];
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(community[1], community[2]);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: community[0],
        url: community[3],
      });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    });
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I knew it was something simple! ;) Thanks so much for your help!